# Simple past or past perfect?

Tags: past-perfect, simple-past

Is this sentence grammatically correct?

> I had felt a strange panic as I was parted from it. (Song of Achilles, Madeline Miller)

It seems rather strange to me to pair the past perfect with the simple past here. If it is ungrammatical, what would be a better alternative? Let me know if more context is needed.

Thanks!

Comment: (1) Lyrics and grammatical correctness are not indissolubly wedded (and so questions involving lyrics are usually off-topic here, as ELU doesn't get involved in '70% ungrammatical or 80% ungrammatical?'-type questions). (2) Here, though, the mismatch of past perfect (setting the timeframe; there must be an intermediate past that this line doesn't directly mention) followed by (passivised) past is not unacceptable – probably even preferable. The past perfect is often ditched as being unwieldy when clarity isn't impaired (and/or ludicrousness introduced) even where it is more logical.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth, I think I understand. Thanks very much for your comment!